# Libsass with Susy not working + Gulp

Tags: sass, gulp, susy, libsass

I've no doubt others have got this working... I just haven't quite worked out how right now.

**Gulp**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var handleErrors = require('../util/handleErrors');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('./frontend/sass/style.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({
            'require':'susy'
        }))
        //.pipe(minifyCSS())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./app/www/css'))
        .on('error', handleErrors)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/www/css'))
});
```

**Sass**

```
@import "susy";
```

**Gulp Running**

```
[23:58:08] Starting 'sass'...

stream.js:94
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
Error: file to import not found or unreadable: susy
Current dir: C:/var/www/rnli.hutber.com/frontend/sass/
```

I have installed susy@2.2.2 in the root along side the `gulp` file with the following: `gem install susy`

**Current working setup with gulp-ruby-sass**

I do however have it working, which confirms that susy is working via the gem installed with the following code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');
var handleErrors = require('../util/handleErrors');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('./frontend/sass/style.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            'sourcemapPath':'./app/www/css',
            'require':'susy'
        }))
        //.pipe(minifyCSS())
        .on('error', handleErrors)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
});
```

**NOTE** The above code will not working using `gulp-ruby-sass@1.0.0alpha' It will only work as I can tell with`v0.7.1`

**package.json**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "~3.8.10",
    "gulp-sass": "~1.3.2",
    "gulp-ruby-sass": "~0.7.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "~1.3.0",
    "susy":"~2.2.1"
  }
```

How do I get `susy` working correctly and able to compile into `css`?

Comment: Not directly on topic, but perhaps helpful, I got [susy and libsass working with ember-cli](https://github.com/ericam/susy/pull/406#issuecomment-69874891).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to get **susy** working with **libsass** (gulp-sass)

**gulp-sass** needs to know where to find files specified with an `@import` directive. You can try set the [includesPath](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#includepaths) option in gulp-sass to point to your local copy of susy.

As I've installed susy with bower, I have something like this:

```
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src(config.src)
    .pipe(sass({
      includePaths: [
        'bower_components/susy/sass'
      ]
    }))
    ...
});
```

Comment: Maybe I need to use it with Bower, but this seems very logically imo :). I am using a similar setup and am trying to include it from my node package. However my file is called `_susy.scss` So I thought maybe I need to change the @import to `_susy`. My project setup is like this > `node_modules¬susy¬sass` so I have tri`ed this with my `gulp.js` being at root. `loadincludePaths: [
    './node_modules/susy/sass//'
   ]` Umm I like the idea however... I just can't get it working.

Comment: Sass partials are prefixed with an underscore, so in the case of `_susy.scss` you would still use `@import "susy";`. Remember that the option for gulp-sass to include a path is `includePaths` and not `loadincludePaths`. Perhaps create a gist of your gulp task in its entirety?

Comment: My bad, i didn't actually do the include with "_susy", I believe if I had it would have errored saying it can't find susy. Indeed changing to includePaths was what got it working for me thus far. if you read the comments on the other answer you'll see where I am at currently.

Comment: @Robin Pyon Why not working `@import "susy";` But it is good worked - `@import "_susy";` ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but with Grunt instead of Gulp.

You could do is use the full path for susy.

First find out where your gems are installed (`gem env`, and look up for `GEM PATHS`; in my case they where in `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0`).

And then in your style.scss file instead of `@import susy` you do:

```
@import "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/susy-2.2.2/sass/susy";
```

(Replace 2.2.2 for your version of susy, but if you are going to use libsass you should use something quite up to date; and you'll have to change that line when you upgrade...)

Not as elegant, but a small price to pay to use libsass.

**Update**: If you put `includePaths: ['/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/susy-2.2.2/sass']` in your Gulp task you can get away with just "`@import susy;`", although you just moved the untidyness somewhere else.

It's probably neater to do it with Bower, as explained in another answer down here, and to have a local susy install for the project; but since I'm not using bower yet (shame on me), I just use a global susy copy for all my projects.

Comment: It got me past the susy error... for sure... However when I started wanting to use susy mixins for example `@include span` It wouldn't recognise the span... Which I find odd indeed.

Comment: That's weird. Could you post your exact import and exact error, please?

Comment: Inside `style.sccs' I'm using: @import "susy"; inside my gulp file `includePaths: ['./node_modules/susy/sass']` First error from `@include border-box-sizing;` Error `Error: no mixin named border-box-sizing`

Comment: Both will indeed work. But I only picked his as he answered first ;)